# Two channels for one API

Tags: rest, architecture, restful-architecture

We have a SaaS. It consists of Single Page application (client), Gateway, Data Service 1, Data Service 2 and Notification Service.
Client talk with Gateway (using REST) and service route the request to appropriate Data Service (1 or 2) or do own calculations.
One request from the client can be split on multiple at Gateway service. The result is an aggregation of responses from the sub-services.
Notification Service - is a service which pushing information about changes made by other users using MQ and WebSocket connection to the client. Notification can be published by any service.

With enginers, we had a discussion how the process can be optimized. 
Currently, the problem that Gateway spending a lot of time just waiting for the response from Data Services.
One of the proposals is letting Gateway service response 200 Ok as soon as message pushed to the Data Service and let client wait for operation progress throw Notification channel (WebSocket connection).

It means that client always sends HTTP request for operation and get confirmation that operation is executed by WebSocket from the different endpoint.

This schema can be hidden by providing JS client library which will hide all this internal complexity.

I think something wrong with this approach. I have never seen such design. But I don't have valuable arguments against it, except complexity and two points of failure (instead of one).

1. What do you think about this design approach?
2. Do you see any potential problems with it?
3. Do you know any public solutions with
   such approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your service is slow it might makes sense to treat it more like a batch job.

1. Client sends a job request to Gateway.
2. Gateway returns a job ID immediately after accepting it from the Client.
3. Client periodically polls the Gateway for results for that job ID.

Comment: Ok. Sounds fine.
Current proposal: wait for job ID on notification service.
What is wrong with this approach?